# How to create a function from the 3 I have written

Tags: python, function, simplify

These 3 functions I have written are all very similar, they all do the scatterplot of 2 variables. Is it possible to create a single function with parameters, instead of having to repeat 3 times similar lines?

```
def plot_RestRate_BMPmax():
    RestRate_list=[]
    BPMmax_list=[]
    for l in range(1,19):
        BPMmax = test[test.ID == l]['BPM'].nlargest(n=5).mean()
        RestRate = test.query(f'time <0 & ID == {l} ')['BPM'].mean()
        BPMmax_list.append(BPMmax)
        RestRate_list.append(RestRate)

    plt.scatter(RestRate_list, BPMmax_list, color='purple')
    a, b = np.polyfit(RestRate_list, BPMmax_list, 1)
    plt.plot(RestRate_list, a*np.array(RestRate_list)+b)
    plt.ylabel('Maximum heart rate')
    plt.xlabel('Rest Rate')
    plt.title('Correlation between Maximum heart rate and Rest Rate')
    plt.show()


def plot_BMP_VO2():
    BPM_list=[]
    VO2_list = []
    for l in range(1,19):
        BPMmax = test[test.ID == l]['BPM'].nlargest(n=5).mean()
        VO2max = test[test.ID == l]['VO2'].nlargest(n=5).mean()
        VO2_list.append(VO2max)
        BPM_list.append(BPMmax)

    plt.scatter(BPM_list, VO2_list,color='purple')
    a, b = np.polyfit(BPM_list, VO2_list, 1)
    plt.plot(BPM_list, a*np.array(BPM_list)+b)
    plt.xlabel('Maximum Heart Rate')
    plt.ylabel('Maximum Oxygen Consumption')
    plt.title('Correlation between Maximum Heart Rate and Maximum Oxygen Consumption')
    plt.show()


def plot_Age_Lactate():
    Age_list=[]
    Lactate_list=[]
    for l in range(1,19):
        Age = test[test.ID == l]['age'].values[0]  
        Lactate = (test[test.ID == l]['VO2'].nlargest(n=5).mean())*(80/100)
        Lactate_list.append(Lactate)
        Age_list.append(Age)

    plt.scatter(Age_list, Lactate_list,color='purple')
    a, b = np.polyfit(Age_list, Lactate_list, 1)
    plt.plot(Age_list, a*np.array(Age_list)+b)
    plt.xlabel('Age')
    plt.ylabel('Lactate threshold')
    plt.title('Correlation between Age and Lactate threshold')
    plt.show()
```

I tried to combine them but since the variables are a little different from one another and I have a for i statement, it just end up not working.

Comment: Create a 4th one just for plotting and have your three original functions call it with proper parameters.

Comment: This would be the perfect solution but it gives me "TypeError: expected 1D vector for x". This is what I wrote.                                                                                                             `def scatterplot(var1, var2):
    plt.scatter(var1, var2,color='purple')
    a, b = np.polyfit(var1, var2, 1)
    plt.plot(var1, a*np.array(var1)+b)
    plt.xlabel(var1)
    plt.ylabel(var2)
    plt.title(f'Correlation between {var1} and {var2}')
    plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Pass calculation functions that accept a number (the looping variable) for `x_calc` and `y_calc`, and then the names for `x_label` and `y_label`.

```py
def plot_stuff(x_calc, y_calc, x_label, y_label, num=18):
    x_list=[]
    y_list=[]
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        x_list.append(x_calc(i))
        y_list.append(y_calc(i))
    plt.scatter(x_list, y_list, color='purple')
    a, b = np.polyfit(x_list, y_list, 1)
    plt.plot(x_list, a*np.array(x_list)+b)
    plt.ylabel(x_label)
    plt.xlabel(y_label)
    plt.title(f'Correlation between {x_label} rate and {y_label}')
    plt.show()
```